# QGIS add/join fields from geosjson

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I want to join some fields from a .geojson file wihtout geometry to another .shp layer.

The join function is not working because I want to keep the fields in the .shp file even then the .geojson has been removed from my QGIS project. And I don't want to export and save the .shp file as well.

Therefore I'm searching for a way to permanently join the fields.

Comment: So, you want to change data permanently, without saving it and without allowing a permanent connection between layers, since you want to remove one of them?

Comment: Yes/No... I want to join the fields of the .geojson table and my .shp file. But after the join I want to remove the .geojson file from my QGIS project and keep the fields and values in the .shp

Comment: Yeah, but you don't want to create a new .shp. So this leaves `aggregate` which is one of the more complicated functions of the field calculator.

Comment: Yes! And is aggregate the only way to do this?

Comment: Probably not, but it defnitely is one of the most clumbersome ways.

Comment: too bad... Hoped there would be another way, THX!

Answer (score 1):

**Use the Field Calculator to copy the joined fields into permanent fields.**

1. After doing the join, put the shapefile layer into edit mode.
2. Use the Field Calculator to copy the values from one of the joined fields into a new field.
3. Repeat step 2 for every joined field.
4. Save the layer edits.

*Example*:

I have a layer joined field called "emission lines_name". To copy this field into a permanent field, I use the Field Calculator to create a new field of the same data type, with the formula `"emission lines_name"`

[image]